# All Properties option not visible in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2022, wdk

I was compiling my solution using VS2022, In the Properties section of solution, I went to general then Modified Windows SDK version and platform toolset to some other values and click applied. The properties menu was changed from first pic to second pic and many options were not there as you can see.

Then I changed the SDK version and platform toolset as they were before and click applied but still can't see the full properties menu as shown in first pic. What could be the reasons my all properties options are not visible as before? How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
File -> Open -> Project/solution
```

I think you just need to open the .sln file on your Windows file explorer.